# Hide Django rest framework Routers Api View Page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, router

I am using DjangoRestFramework 3.3.2 for Routing in my django application. I have 6 different folders for 6 apps and 1 main project app. I have include all 6 apps urls into main url file. Following is my main url file.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^vpc/', include('vpc.urls')),
    url(r'^dss/', include('dss.urls')),
    url(r'^rds/', include('rds.urls')),
    url(r'^compute/', include('compute.urls')),
    url(r'^iam/', include('iam.urls')),
]
```

And this is my one of app url file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers
import views.instance_views as instance
import views.snapshot_views as snapshot

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'instance', instance.IntanceViewSet, base_name='instance')
router.register(r'snapshot', snapshot.SnapshotViewSet, base_name='snapshot')

urlpatterns = []

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Now my problem is when I open urls in browser, I can see whole url hierarchy. Which is not required.[image: Snapshot of Api root view]

How do I hide these rendered views. I don't want to show any extra information

I was able to hide view using:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

But I am still getting all urls under 1 app.

```
{"instance":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/compute/instance/","keypair":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/compute/keypair/","volume":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/compute/volume/","image":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/compute/image/","snapshot":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/compute/snapshot/"}
```

Comment: Didn't see something about this in the settings, but you could try adding an view with the url `compute/$` (note the $) to return e.g a 401, it should leave deeper urls of the router as-is.

Answer (score 15):

In your urls.py change the default router to simple router.

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
```

You should also add the following snippet in your production settings file to only enable JSONRenderer for the API, This will completely disable the web browsable API.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to update on the answers given. You do need to specify the `SimpleRouter()` router, but often the `DefaultRouter()` router is useful for viewing and debugging whilst in development.

With that in mind, I would advise doing the simple following step:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    router = DefaultRouter()
else:
    router = SimpleRouter()
```

Then as normal:

```
from myproject.users.api.viewsets import UserViewSet

router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

after create instance from `DefaultRouter` you should set `include_root_view` to False

```
v1_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
v1_router.include_root_view = False
```

Answer (score -3):

In settings.py `DEBUG=False` and your REST API wont show.

Comment: DEBUG was already set to 'False'. I fixed it by replacing 'DefaultRouter' with 'SimpleRouter'. Now its just giving '404 error' instead of Api url hierarchy.

Comment: Debug also set to false on our side and still seing root page